# How to install vnc server so I can have complete control on my Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 12.04, server, sudo, remote-desktop, vnc

I installed ubuntu server 12.04. I installed gnome desktop on that (GUI essential for my purpose). Now I want to control the server remotely. I tried following things and not very successful :

1)Installed xrdp , but it is very laggy. Not useful for me.
2)Installed nomachine, it is better than xrdp but not good enough for my purpose.
3)Installed VNC server and used tigerVNC to connect it. It gave the best result. I want to continue to use it. But I am facing following problems :

- I cant login as root through VNC. (Is it possible, Kindly tell me
  how to do.)
- vncuser account dont have sufficient privilleges. I    added it to
  sudoers list. But there are n number of technical    glitches. Got
  problem in installing softwares. Can't start chrom web    browser and
  a lot of different things.

So can anybody tell me how to get access to my remote server through tiger vnc and have complete control on my server? If there is any other solution apart from using tiger vnc , I am open to it.

Comment: "I cant login as root through VNC." Why would you want to do that in the first place? I hope you're not running your desktop environment as root - as that is really not a good idea security-wise.

Comment: Security is not an issue for me. I am searching for very user friendly solution. I want to run some heavy graphic GUI apps on my server. I should be able to access to it from anywhere smoothly.

Comment: In that case you are not looking for VNC. It has nothing concerning hardware acceleration, no video support, etc. It will just repaint pixel by pixel. NX is what gets closest, I believe. Also read up on SPICE in KVM virtual machines. While that works in virtual environments only, it provides several nice features towards VDI and much smoother experience.

Comment: NX was not as smooth as the tiger VNC was. I tried both. The problem I faced is vncuser dont have much permission. Is it possible to login as root by using a vnc client?

Answer (score 0):

Try either one of the following;

- install **xrdp** package and connect through RDP client e.g Remote Desktop client if using Windows or another client like Remmina client.
- Install Teamviewer (my prefferred) and configure it to start automattically and set an unattended access password for it. Then connect to it also with another TeamViewer installed on the other machine (Team viewer has a very good graphics and performance especially in LAN connections as it uses a direct connection rather than connecting through Team Viewer servers "if you don't have Internet connection, just connect using machine IP instead of TeamViewer ID and it will use LAN connection automatically")